# How to query several sql columns

Tags: php, sql

I wanted to make a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments AND name WHERE id = 1 OR name = '1'
```

I want it to return every row that has the `id = 1` or `name = 1` or both.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried doing what you just typed there?  What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot one table. I want to make a query to two tables and return those values

Comment: Please provide some information about the tables. Without that info we'd have to show you a blind join, and that would be a bad thing.

Comment: table comments has the fields: id, comment
table name has the fields: id, name

For the sake of the example I want to return all that has the id 1 and the name pihh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are querying this from a single table your syntax would be -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` = 1 OR `name` = 'one'
```

For two tables to be joined

```
SELECT `name`.`name`, `comments`.`comment`
FROM `name`
LEFT JOIN `comments`
ON `name`.`id` = `comments`.`id`
WHERE `name`.`name` = 'pihh'
```

The names and the comments would be joined to some common column, in this case I have used `id`.

Answer (score 0):

When querying more than one table (as you mention in your comment) you need to `JOIN` them before applying `WHERE` conditions.

For your query there needs to be a primary/foreign key which link the tables; I assume there is a `name_id` or similar foreign key in the `comments` table which tells you who made a comment.

Therefore your query needs to be more like

```
SELECT *
FROM comments INNER JOIN [name_table] ON comments.name_id = [name_table].name_id
WHERE id = 1 OR name = '1'
```

You will have to replace table and field names as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I am assume you used AND between comments and name because you have two tables called comments and name. I have also changed you name = '1' to name='name' bcoz it makes more sense.

```
 SELECT * FROM comments.id 
 LEFT JOIN name ON comment.id = name.id 
 WHERE comment.id = 1 
 OR name.name = 'name'
```